# How to do actions on 2 browser concurrently using Selenium on one computer?

Tags: java, selenium, concurrency

I am doing a blackbox testing using Selenium and Java. I want to open two browsers and do some actions (like click buttons, fill some text-field...) on these browsers at the same time, so that I can see how the system will response. I searched for this problem and knowed about Selenium Grid. But it seems to run on several machines, not one machine.

I want to know if there are any simple solution for my question, which I don't need to install any tools else. I try to use Thread but it is useless.

Comment: This is news to me, I honestly didn't know that a java application could do some sort of remote desktop. But, out-of-the-box thinking: have you tried using a virtual machine (e.g. [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/))? If Selenium only allows you to run in different machines, this would manage to create another machine environment inside the same machine, where you could run another browser... Do you get my point?

Comment: Have you tried using TestNg to run tests in parallel?

Comment: If you're using selenium for testing purposes, you should be using a testing framework, such as JUnit or TestNG.  These testing frameworks have support for parallelism built in.  Try looking around for parallel test execution with your testing framework of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I still believe using Threads is the best possible solution available. Even though Threads cannot be executed in parallel (it is up to the JVM or OS to decide when a thread should be run), we can switch between the threads using the following code. The switch would happen in milliseconds interval and would look almost parallel like.

Feedback is welcome on what can be improved.

Please find the code below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class App implements Runnable {

    WebDriver driver;
    String threadName;

    public App(String threadName, WebDriver driver) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void run() {

        if (threadName.equals("one")) {
            System.out.println("one : " + driver.getTitle());
        } else {
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        }

        if (threadName.equals("one")) {
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        } else {
            System.out.println("two : " + driver.getTitle());
        }

        if (threadName.equals("one")) {
            System.out.println("one one one");
        } else {
            System.out.println("two two two");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver1.get("https://www.google.com");

        WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver2.get("https://en.wikipedia.com");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
        executor.execute(new App("one", driver1));
        executor.execute(new App("two", driver2));
    }
}
```

Output would look like below(This might vary because of random Thread switch)

> one : Google
>   Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>   Google
>   one one one
>   two : Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>   two two two